# Include additional information of figure somewhere else

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, appendix

I‘m writing a thesis in computer science. A big part of my work involves running simulations with software I programmed.

For all the images produced by the simulation, I want to show the reader how that result can be reproduced on his machine. Stupid example, I might show a graph for `y=2x` and tell the reader: „Oh yeah, you can get the same plot by running `gcc -DPLOT=2x main.c other.c` on your machine.“

Since that information is not directly relevant to my research, I want to include that information somewhere else.

Here‘s what I have come up with so far:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Let's look at the following computationally generated graph.

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{universe}
\caption[The Universe compiled with: gcc -DCOLOR=blue -o a.out main.cpp helpers.cpp other.cpp]{The Universe}
\label{fig:universe}
\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image: document showing command line information in list of figures]

What I particularly like about this setup is that I can put the compilation information right into my figure.

Obviously the end result doesn‘t look as nice. Is there a way to format the list of figures, eg. by adding a line break and formatting the additional information to be monospace?

I could also imagine that the List of Figures isn‘t the optimal location to include that information. If that‘s the case, is there a standard way to do what I want? (maybe using an Appendix)

Comment: The optional argument of \caption is used for the LOF:  \caption[short version]{long version}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yeah, that‘s why I kinda figured it shouldn‘t be used this way

Comment: The supplemental information would indeed seem to be best placed in an appendix, using an `enumerate` list environment. That, or a `longtable` environment, which allows page breaks.

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard way to add such information. Maybe you can repurpose the `glossaries` package for this in some way. But writing your own `\supplementary` command (or something similar) that mimics `\caption` (i.e., contains the current figure counter, page number, possibly a `hyperref` link) should not be too difficult. Then you can also customize the appearance of the supplementary information more easily.

Comment: I've always been a big fan of appendices.  The big question is whether this is for print or whether you can use hyperref links.

Comment: @JohnKormylo It will be printed, no hyperrefs unfortunately. I thought of implementing something Marijn mentioned above (using glossaries), but I'm not too familiar with extending LaTeX commands

Comment: You can include text and other things in the figure environment, if they are small.  Larger items can be placed in figures without captions.  They should be located close to each other (in the correct order).